# JavaScript object buried nest

Tags: javascript, object, html5-canvas

I'm writing a canvas GUI handler called lightning, and it's stored as an object

```
var lightning = {}
```

Inside of this object there are many functions, variables and nested objects, such as `render`, `handleClickEvent`, and `image`. For the purposes of this question, lightning is structured like this:

```
var lightning = {
     render : function(){
          // rendering script
     },
     image : {
          load : function(source) {
               // Adds image to image storage
               // Generates and returns image ID
               // [[calls lightning.render()]]
          }
     }
}
```

My question is, how do I call `lightning.render` without going into the global scope and calling `lightning.render`, so it wouldn't break if I were to rename lightning to notLightning... how would I call lightning.render from within itself, but nested kinda deep?

*Btw* there is also an `init` function in lightning where I could set a variable inside the image object to point to lightning's `self`, but I don't know how to do that.

Thank you,

-Dylan

Comment: `this.image.self = this` in `init` should do it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with referring to `lightning.render`. If you want to be able to rename it without a proper refactoring, you can use the module pattern (which you probably should use anyway instead of an `init` function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple.

As I had mentioned, there is an `init` function which is called to construct lightning. In `lightning.image`, I created a variable, `that`, and in `lightning.init`, I set `this.image.that = this`

This was I was just able to call `this.that.update()` in `lightning.image.add`.

Thanks for your help, @Bergi

Comment: I didn't use `self` because that is reserved for a window object in many browsers :)